# picture ad.jpg won't show in browser: antivirus issue?

Tags: image, browser, hidden, antivirus

I'm facing a weird problem with an online card game:

Out of 2 million games played in 2012, two users complained they can never see the Ace of Diamonds, named "ad.jpg".
This happened whatever the browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome...) and I suspect it has to do with the name of the picture.

If I rename it say da.jpg it shows. But I can't easily rename it for all the recorded games are using ad.jpg.

Any clue would e appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue:

Kasperski was  in use with the two users that reported the problem.
According to one of these users,, here's the solution:

One option of Kaspersky is called "Anti-Banner."  In the words of the Kaspersky Labs people, "This feature blocks ads and banners in your web browser and in some applications."  I discovered that this feature was enabled on my Compaq/HP computer (the one on which the Ace of Diamonds was invisible) but not on the other two.

Accordingly, I turned this feature OFF on the Compaq/HP, and voila:  the Ace of Diamonds became visible, as did various other previously-invisible files that were of interest to me (but whose names contained the letters "ad" or "ads", with the "a" being either the very first character or the character immediately following a slash.)

I subsequently turned the Anti-Banner feature ON again on the Compaq/HP, intending to re-create the problem so that I could investigate further and ascertain precisely what combination of factors was causing the trouble.  However, the "invisible ace of diamonds" problem did NOT reappear -- it's all working okay now -- and as a result I have only the vague idea of the cause of this problem that I have outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect not anti-virus, but possibly some sort of simplistic ad-block software (proxy/plugin), that blocks images containing 'ad' (advert).

I'd suggest copying the image, and using the new name for new games, and leaving ad.jpg for old games.